# Octopus Depoy, How can I create a release with a subset of my process steps?

Tags: octopus-deploy

I want to create a release but not with the full set of deployment steps. I want to cherry-pick just a few for the release, but I don't want to permanently remove those steps.  I believe this can be done through the UI but can't recall the process and the can't find it addressed in the documentation.

Answer (score 2):

After you choose to deploy a release, you can choose advanced and then selectively skip any steps you don't want included.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use Channels (Octopus 3.3+) to do this on a more permanent basis.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to jchadhowell's method (manual intervention), you can also specify those steps only run on a trivial environment instead of all. Hacky but works for automatic deployments :)

[image]